# React native screens configuration failed

Tags: react-native

trying to build an android project,and gradle fails with this exception:

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'archiveClassifier' for task ':react-native-screens:androidJavadocJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PR that created this change](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens/pull/60) you need Gradle 4.10+. So if you update it should work again. You need to update the version of the gradle plugin to 3.3.2 as well. I'm not sure but I do think you could even update to Gradle 5.x and build plugin 3.4+.

[Link referenced to Create My Answer](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens/issues/124#issuecomment-510413468)